# limit the width of an h1 element to its parent

Tags: css

I want to limit the width of the hd  but without having to set a width. I want it to occupy the full available width (width of the parent?)

```css
.wrapper {
  outline: 1px #000 solid;
  width: 600px;
  margin: auto;
  display: flex;
}

.left {
  flex-grow: 1
}

.left h1 {
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis
}

.right {
  width: 200px;
  background-color: #CCC;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="left">
    <h1>this is a really really really long heading</h1>
  </div>
  <div class="right">right</div>
</div>
```

Comment: so you want the font to fill the complete line?

Comment: Have you tried width:100%

Comment: `min-width: 0;` to left element

Comment: don't add the answer into the question. The question need to remain a question and show the initial issue

Comment: If I understand your question correctly, you can solve it by adding `overflow: hidden` to `.left`

Comment: yeah sorry was testing in the snipper. min-width: 0 fixed my problem. thank you.